# All of my files has been disappeared

Tags: restore

Dear friends yesterday I came against with a problem that never have been faced the last 15 years I use Ubuntu. I was trying to repair  linux-image-header 6.5.0.1 because a had dpkg warning message during update via terminal. Suddenly I lost Downloads, Common Share, Music, desktop and every directory. I reseted user folders by xdg-user-dirs-update --force. The problem is that all files has been disappeared. Photorec restored other files but not even one of these I lost.Is there any way to restore these lost files? Is there a chance to be hidden somewhere in disk that I don't know?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151423/discussion-on-question-by-elias-dou-all-of-my-files-has-been-disappeared); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)